# ListBox (MultiSelect) Click Event

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trigger some event upon clicking certain options in listbox1. I can achieve this when listbox1 is set to SelectSingle. But when using fmMultiSelectMulti property, it does not work. Below is simple code I am using to test the clicking.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
If ListBox1.Selected(0) Then MsgBox "Nice"
End Sub
```

I click the first option and I thought it would trigger the MsgBox. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Edit: Using the change event worked!

Comment: Try using the Change event instead.

Comment: That worked! Confused as to why Click Event was not triggering.

Comment: How Can I prevent the change event from firing when clicking another option? For example, I click Option A, trigger the event which prompts the user to enter a Value into a input Box. I then Click Option B, which has a different prompt. Doing this still triggers the first event for Option A then for Option B. Is there a way to only trigger the change event once for each option?

Comment: Track which indices you've handled and only conditionally prompt?

Comment: Is using click event not possible at all? It would simplify the code significantly.